# Short story about boy with computer powers (and a disk slot in his forehead)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers, mutation

I read this in *Analog* I think - it's probably from the 1980s. I think the story takes place on the moon - or some other location dominated by corridors. The man character is a man dating a woman with a young son - a boy who creeps the man out, and has an odd straight wrinkle/scar in his forehead. The story ends as the man is found guilty of computer crime based on evidence on floppy discs (or something very like them); the man realizes that the kid set him up, altering the data on the discs by inserting the discs into the slot on his forehead  - a mutant ability the kid has.  Not a great story, but one that I'd like to identify.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty crappy mutant superpower.  It's only good for, what, 20-25 years, and then you've got this useless thing in your head and nothing to use it on...

Comment: @DavidW assuming the power is specifically "read floppy disk" and not "read/alter digital media" (presumably at a microscopic level)...though some sci-fi does not age well.

Comment: Yesterday's technology goes away - today's tech is eternal. Sliderules and vacuum tubes in space....

Comment: @DavidW - We have lots of examples of mature technologies. Toaster ovens and microwaves haven't really moved on in the last 75 years.